# Why aren't the scavengers affected by the toxin in the kaiju blood?

Tags: pacific-rim

In the movie “Pacific Rim”, isn’t it stated that kaiju blue is toxic to humans? Now, in the scene when the scavengers came up and started scavenging otachi, they appeared to be directly exposed to the kaiju blue when they took of the organs of that kaiju. Why did they expose themselves to the kaiju blue? Wouldn’t that kill them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a transcript of the movie dialogue (Apologies, not sure who is speaking):

> Uh, yeah, right, um, black market dealers, right?
>
> Yep. They're in and out in a matter of hours. They neutralize the acidic factor of the blood...and they harvest what they need.

So the scavengers have developed methods of neutralizing the blood, as well as preserving various items (As seen in the later scene inside Hannibal Chau's lab, where he has perfectly preserved Kaiju items):

> **Newt**: Oh, my God! Oh, my God, this place is heaven! That's a lymph gland from a Category 2! And what are you working on here? Is this a cuticle? In mint condition? Is that a Kaiju skin parasite? I've never seen them alive before!
>   They usually die as soon as the Kaiju falls!
>
> **Newt**: I thought you couldn't keep them alive!
>
> **Hannibal Chau**: - You can if you soak them in ammonia.